# Open shell in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell

How can I open in Python a unix shell, type a command and some other inputs and close the unix shell?

Example commands and inputs:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1:6000
user
pass
save-all
restart
```

Greets

miny

Comment: [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)?

Comment: seems you want to use the telnet program and propably write/read to stdin/stdou of telnet. there is no (bash) shell at all.

Comment: Have you given a look to the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html)? Also, are you sure you need a shell at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the `pexpect` module and more precisely the interact function.
See documentation [here](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn-interact).

Basically, you juste spawn your sheel, program or whatever you want, and interact with it like you would normally do.

```
import pexepect
p = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
p.interact()
```

Then you escape with an escape character as explained in the doc.